How to Verify if User is Accessing Website via Telegram Mobile App in PHP?
I everyone, hope You're fine, I'm working on a PHP-based website and I need to ensure that users are accessing the site through the Telegram mobile app (both iOS and Android). If the user is not using the Telegram mobile app, I want to display a message instructing them to switch to the app.
I have no prior experience with this type of verification. How can I achieve this? Are there any specific methods or headers I should look for in the HTTP request to identify access via the Telegram mobile app?
Verification must work for both iOS and Android Telegram apps.
Display a message to the user if they are not accessing the site via the Telegram mobile app.
Since this must be the first verification, there is no prior code to be shown...
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

The app would have to send some unique, secret authentication token to the server which only the app can know. A server-side application receiving a HTTP request has no built-in mechanism for knowing what kind of client made the request to it - HTTP doesn't include such info in its protocol (other than people sometimes use the user-agent header, but that's easy to fake).

P.S. Why do you care how people make requests to your server-side code? Seems a bit restrictive

In this case the restriction is only due to this website being specifically built to host telegram games, loaded by the bot only (or that was the initial idea).
I've seen some games that can even see if you're using telegram mobile or telegram desktop but I cannot find any solution around...

Check what the User-Agent request header, and the HTTP referrer contain. Most likely those other apps you mentioned, base their decision on one of these.
